# Why does try catch not catch Sql syntax error

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm adding an inputbox to my site where I as the admin can enter sql select statements, I put a try catch around the code that executes the select to try and catch syntax errors but even with this my site goes to the "error in application / " page when there is a syntax error.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am developing on Asp.net v4.

The code that executes the custom SQL command is as follows;

```
 try
 {
      //edtSQL.Text = "WHRE Field='Value'"
      //The Resulting SQL Command will be incorrect because of incorrect syntax
      SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM DataTable " + edtSQL.Text;
      SqlDataSource1.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
       //Bad Syntax should be caught here, but it is not. This never get called
       // even when there is a syntax error.
       lblQueryStatus.Text = "Error, can't execute SQL statment";
 }
```

Instead if the label showing the error message, the site gives an error and goes to the  default site error page.

Comment: Can you provide your code, specifically your on click handler for the button/

Comment: Are you sure that an exception isn't being thrown elsewhere?  Are you catching all exceptions or just `SqlException`s?

Comment: Please post your relevant code. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @KeaganLadds: I've reopened so that you can add an answer detailing what the solution was.  You can then select it as the correct answer and close out this question.  Thanks for improving your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch in the above code does actually catch the exception. On the exception set the Select Command to something default that is sure to work ie.

```
SELECT * FROM Database
```

And Execute the select. The reason for this is when the page does a post back it tries to execute the select statement that has been set for it and there is not try catch around this(because its in another context) and this is why the server then defaults to the "error in application / " page.

The code should look like this

```
try
{
  //edtSQL.Text = "WHRE Field='Value'"
  //The Resulting SQL Command will be incorrect because of incorrect syntax
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM DataTable " + edtSQL.Text;
  SqlDataSource1.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM DataTable"; //This will work for sure
   SqlDataSource1.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
   lblQueryStatus.Text = "Error, can't execute SQL statment";
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you should definitely use SqlParameters;  `"SELECT * FROM DataTable " + edtSQL.Text;` leaves you wide open for injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into how to do that.